# Multiple Markers on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying achieve multiple markers on a Google map to mark access points for a river. So far I have one marker (myLatlng) that displays and anotehr that shows after a button is clicked, however when I have tried adding more than one (accessPoint1), it will not appear. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```js
    function initialize() {
    
     var myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(51.843143, -2.643555),
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                zoom: 12, 
                center: myLatlng}),
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title:"We are here!"
                  });
      
      
  var accessPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.840913, -2.638603),
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                zoom: 12, 
                center: accessPoint1}),
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: accessPoint1,
                  map: map,
                  title:"Access Point 1" 
                  });
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push($("#findButton")[0]);
    
      function successCallback(position) { 
        var latlng    = new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude, 
                                                position.coords.longitude),
            
            myOptions = {
              zoom: 3,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeControl: false,
              navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latlng);
        
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        
        map.setOptions(myOptions);
        
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        
        new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map,
                  title:"You are here!",
                  icon:'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png'
                  });
      }
      
      function errorCallback() {
        alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
      }
       
    function findMe(){
        $(this).hide();
        
        if (navigator.geolocation){
             navigator.geolocation
             .getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,{timeout:10000});
        }
        else{
          alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
        }
      }
      
      $("#findButton").click(findMe);
    }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the map for the second access point, which means you have two maps, each having one marker on it, the first of which is overwritten and not visible.  You are also overwriting the marker variable (which shouldn't cause an issue):

Unless you have multiple `<div>`'s with maps in them, only create one map.

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.843143, -2.643555),
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng
        }),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "We are here!"
        });


    var accessPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.840913, -2.638603),
        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: accessPoint1,
            map: map,
            title: "Access Point 1"
        });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push($("#findButton")[0]);

    function successCallback(position) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude),

            myOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latlng);

        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

        map.setOptions(myOptions);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "You are here!",
            icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png'
        });
    }

    function errorCallback() {
        alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }

    function findMe() {
        $(this).hide();

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
                timeout: 10000
            });
        } else {
            alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
        }
    }

    $("#findButton").click(findMe);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```